# Unable to access properties of model (vs Model)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Currently I have a view which takes an IEnumerable model which I use to display data on the view.  However on the same view I also have a modal popup in which I want to add to the model rather than separating them out into different views.  I tried to follow the suggestion at the bottom of this question [How to access model property in Razor view of IEnumerable Type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8652082/how-to-access-model-property-in-razor-view-of-ienumerable-type) but got an exception

> The expression compiler was unable to evaluate the indexer expression '(model.Count - 1)' because it references the model parameter 'model' which is unavailable.

At the top of the view I have

```
@model IList<Test.Models.DashModel>
```

and within my modal body I have

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>DashboardModel</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model[model.Count - 1].DashName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model[model.Count - 1].DashName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model[model.Count - 1].DashName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model[model.Count - 1].CreatedDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model[model.Count - 1].CreatedDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model[model.Count - 1].CreatedDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: try Model.Count (with caps M)

Comment: Since you view has a form to edit one object only, then why on earth are you passing a collection to the view instead of one object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree that overuse of the word *Model*, i.e. the `@model` keyword, the `Model` instance variable of the same type, and the default name `model` given to the lambda parameter name of the `HtmlHelper` methods is really confusing.

Unfortunately `model` in this case is the parameter passed by the `Html.*For` extension methods into your lambda. IMO the scaffolded views could have chosen a less conflicting parameter variable name for the lambdas, e.g. `m` or `x` etc.

To access the actual `ViewModel` instance passed to the view (i.e. `@model` defined at the top of your razor `.cshtml`, viz `@model IList<Test.Models.DashModel>`), what you want to do is to access **`Model`** (note the case difference):

```
  @Html.LabelFor(model => Model.Last().CreatedDate, ...
```

I would also recommend using the `Linq` extension methods such as `Last() / First()` etc rather than using the array indexers.

Out of interest, you can of course change the parameter name to anything you like, e.g.

```
  @Html.LabelFor(_ => Model.Last().CreatedDate, ...
```